# Change column from Checkboxes back to Drop-down - what data will it delete?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I had a column that was a drop-down, and we wanted to experiment with the checkboxes; however, that was causing issues with our data analysis. I want to switch back to drop-down; however, it says that data might be deleted. What data will be deleted? Is it just the ones with multiple checkboxes or everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Choice with Checkboxes allows multiple values. Choice with Drop-down Menu or Radio Buttons only allows one value.

When you change the type of the column from Choice with Checkboxes to Choice with Drop-down Menu or Radio Buttons, it will not move choices from the choice column and will not delete choice values from existing items.

When you edit an existing item where there are multiple values in the choice column, you will find there is no value displayed in the Choice with Drop-down Menu or Radio Buttons. You need to re-select a new value for this column by clicking the drop down or the radio.

[image]